IBM MQ 9.1 compatibility with RHEL 8.10
We are currently running IBM MQ 9.1.0.5 on RHEL 7.9. Since this version of RHEL has announced EOS we are planning to migrate to RHEL 8.
is IBM MQ 9.1.0.5 compatible with RHEL 8.10 ?

Yes, IBM MQ 9.1 is supported on RHEL 8.10 - see this page (defaults to showing 9.1, select the most recent maintenance level to view the latest set of supported platforms):
https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=B560B760819A11E6B5854315721876AE&osPlatforms=Linux#!
This shows RHEL 8 has been supported from IBM MQ 9.1.0.4, the details view for RHEL 8 shows support for RHEL 8.10.
Note: The RDQM capability of IBM MQ 9.1 is only supported on RHEL 7.
Be aware IBM MQ 9.1 is also EoS - https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/announcement-end-support-ibm-mq-910-lts-and-ibm-mq-91x-cd
